# why ' grep -w -e "[SVC]" *.* ' doesn't return anything?

Tags: linux, grep

why  `grep -w -e "[SVC]"  *.*`  (with upper case characters) doesn't return anything but when I use lower case characters
`grep -w -e "[svc]" *.*` it returns the result as expected?
[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the *first* thing you have to ascertain is whether there are actually any words in the file made up of a single ***uppercase*** letter drawn from the set `{S, V, C, P}`.

The `-w` flag will restrict you to *words* of that form so it would, for example, find `P.x`. It would *not* find `ValidParentheses`. The detail can be found in the manpage:

> The `-w` option selects only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The test is that the matching substring must ***either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.*** Similarly, it must be ***either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.***

Comment: with this logic shouldn't it return `isValid`?

Comment: Ok! So I did some permutation combinations.. Here's my understanding.. because of `-e` flag and brackets `[ ]`, it's attempting to match any line containing individual caps characters: `S`, `V`, `C` . However, because of combination with `-w` flag, it's now looking for individual characters which are also words (like variable name `v` is). So it would match only single characters which are words (And not part of other words).

Comment: @AnupamJain: it will not match `isValid` because the `V` is next to a word-constituent character (`s` on the left and `a` on the right, though any *one* of those would stop the match).